# Who are all the people who had dreams of becoming Hokage?

Tags: character, naruto

While watching *Boruto: Naruto Next Generations*, I noticed that the new main character Sarada Uchiha wants to become the Hokage.

If I am not wrong there were many people who wanted to become Hokage in the Naruto show. I remember a few, Naruto, Obito Uchiha, Nawaki, etc., but I am sure there were more. It was a constant driving ambition in the show. So I want to know, who are all the people in the Naruto show who wanted to become the Hokage?

Comment: @Paulie_D I am sure there will be less then 10 people and it's a distinct list question which worked fine in past

Comment: @Paulie_D where did I said I need 100s of partial answer? I asked for full answer

Comment: @Paulie_D question title Who are **all the** people who had dream to become Hokage?

Comment: That's the issue with list questions (even limited scope ones). You get single answers with one example each. Not **one answer with them all**.

Comment: @Paulie_D luckily existing answer is in far better state now and will work for me

Answer (score 7):

## Naruto

Of course. Source: Watch the anime.

## Uchiha Obito

His motivations are very much like Naruto's:

> Feeling alone in the world, Obito dreamed of becoming Hokage so that the people of the village would acknowledge his existence.
>   <sub>[Naruto Wikia - Uchiha Obito](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Obito_Uchiha)</sub>

## Uchiha Sasuke

One character you didn't mention in the question yet is **Uchiha Sasuke**. All the way at the end of the manga, in episode 692, he states his intentions:

> My only wish was my revenge. Sure, back then, the only thing I wanted was pure destruction. But it's different now.
>
> Rebuild a new world for us! One that cannot be tainted by darkness. I will destroy and rebuild.
>
> What I'm pushing for is a revolution!
>
> It's the current kages that have made things turn out this way and that's why I'll become Hokage and change the village.

[image] 
[image]

[Source](http://www.mangapanda.com/naruto/692)

## Shimura Danzo

In chapter 285 it is revealed that Danzo competed with Sarutobi for becoming 3rd Hokage, but failed. He ended up becoming the 6th Hokage though.

> Tsunade: He competed for the chair of Sandaime Hokage with the late Sarutobi-Sensei. He's different to Sandaime. He's an overly serious, militaristic, logical thinking leader.

[image]

## Inuzuka Kiba

Kiba, one of the yearmates of Naruto, also has these ambitions.

> Kiba also dreams of becoming the Hokage someday and expressed this desire both during his fight with Naruto during the Chūnin Exams as well as during the Fourth Shinobi World War, where he deduced that if he fought and gained a name for himself during the war, it would be a step in the direction of becoming the Hokage, an ideal he mentions again later on. In his Infinite Tsukuyomi, Kiba dreamed he was Hokage and also desired to have a national holiday for all dogs.
>   <sub>[Naruto wikia - Kiba Inuzuka](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kiba_Inuzuka)</sub>
>
> Kiba to Naruto: You become hokage?! Even though you're weaker than me?!! You don't actually think you can become Hokage!! Stop acting tough, hehe... If you wnat a Hokage... I'll become one!!

[image]

[Source](http://www.mangapanda.com/naruto/76/10)

## Kato Dan

The lover of Tsunade, the Godaime Hokage, Dan Kato shared Tsunade's aspirations of becoming a Hokage:

> After the death of his younger sister, he began advocating for medical ninja to be assigned to every squad. Tsunade shared a similar belief, and the two soon began dating because of it. During their time together Dan shared his dream of becoming Hokage with Tsunade — wanting the title so that he could better protect the villagers of Konoha which would prompt Tsunade to give Dan her grandfather's necklace as good luck and encouragement to follow that dream.
>   <sub>[Naruto Wikia - Dan Kato](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Dan_Kat%C5%8D)</sub>

## Orochimaru

One of the (many) big bads in the Naruto series. He did intend to become Hokage, but for his own purpose.

> Orochimaru was a prime candidate to be the Fourth Hokage, but was passed over because he didn't embody the Will of Fire.
>   <sub>[Naruto Wikia - Hokage](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hokage)</sub>

The third Hokage did suspect him though, so this ship didn't sail.

> Sandaime Hokage to Orochimaru: One of the reasons I didn't choose you to be the Yondaime was because of your twisted ideology.

[image]

[Source](http://www.mangapanda.com/naruto/121/7)

## Nawaki

> He was the younger brother of Tsunade and the grandson of Hashirama and Mito. He was also the grandnephew of Tobirama. He shared his dream of becoming Hokage with his sister on his twelfth birthday, who gave him their grandfather's necklace in the hopes that it would help him achieve his dream. The day after his birthday, Nawaki died in battle after running into an explosive trap. When Tsunade rushed to him, Orochimaru noted that his body was so heavily mutilated that it was beyond recognition. The necklace was retrieved by Orochimaru and returned to a devastated Tsunade.
>   <sub>[Naruto Wikia - Nawaki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nawaki)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Well, apart from the characters that JAD mentioned, I think there were 2 more (that's all I can remember now, if I remember others I will update the answer later) !!

### [Konohamaru](https://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Konohamaru_Sarutobi)

I don't remember in which chapter, but it is the chapter where he met Naruto for the first time. There he said that he wanted to be the hokage and from that moment naruto is his role model but rival also.

[image]

### [Kushina](https://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kushina_Uzumaki)

When Kushina was a new kid in the school, she expressed that she wanted to be the [first female hokage of the village](https://bleachsoulevolution.com/forum/manga/Naruto/498/11) and [everyone mocked her](https://bleachsoulevolution.com/forum/manga/Naruto/498/12).

[image]

Comment: Also, all the actual Hokage

Comment: And Uchiha Madara

Comment: @BlueMoon93 I too thought Madara wanted to be hokage but I could not find any proof...  https://66.media.tumblr.com/402091572303b3fedd1e36d59da67464/tumblr_inline_mkcv3otJhy1qz4rgp.png...the manga page said it was Hasirama who wanted Madara to be the first hokage.

Comment: @BlueMoon93  probably Tsunade and Kakashi didn't want to be hokages, no ?

Comment: @Spectra Tsunade was forced and Kakashi become out of nowhere

Comment: @AnkitSharma ohh yeah..Jiraiya refused and Tsunade was made the hokage

Comment: @Spectra she also denied but lost the bet to naruto so have to

Comment: Ahh..memory's fading..gotta go back and watch those again sometime..':)